# Java - appending to Excel file with FileOutputStream

Tags: java, append, fileoutputstream

This code appends to an already created Excel file:

```
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("c:\\Decrypted.xls");
```

What can we add / modify so that Decrypted.xls should be created if not already created and appended if already created?

Comment: There isn't anything specific to Excel files. That could just as well be edited out.

Comment: I wonder what the purpose of this is? Somehow I doubt that the result will be a working, bigger Excel file with more data in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the Javadocs for the String-accepting constructor of FileOutputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.lang.String%29), rover12, if the file doesn't already exist then it's created.  Are you not seeing this behavior?

(And as others have mentioned, be sure to use [the constructor that takes the second boolean argument](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) so you can specify that you want to append the file if it already exists...)

Comment: no i am not seeing this behaviour .. if i delete the already existing Decrypted.xls i get an error compliling that says .. file does not exist

Answer (score 1):

You want the `FileOutputStream(File file, boolean append)` constructor for switching on whether you truncate or append.

Answer (score 0):

Use the constructor:

```
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("c:\\Decrypted.xls", true);
```

to append to an existing file, if it doesn't exist. Your example will overwrite the existing one.